# Granular permissions needed to take Active Directory snapshot

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

Short and sweet, I am using ntdsutil in a script/scheduled task to take AD snapshots. The service account running the scheduled task is in the Domain Admins group so its gets proper permissions. I locked down the account a bit for no local logons, etc...

Are there specific permission objects I can give the account just so it can take the AD snapshots instead of it being a full blown domain admin?

I searched around a bit and didn't really find anything.

Comment: As you mentioned 2012 in the tags, I'd recommend changing the account to a [gMSA](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2012/12/16/windows-server-2012-group-managed-service-accounts/) if it's not already. No more password to manage. I don't have any additional information on the snapshot permissions though.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the default build-in backup operator achieve what you need? Non-Domain Admin account that can backup AD system states?
[Backing Up Active Directory](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961924.aspx)

It has logon permission to the DCs